# How can I extract just the domain from a url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to track where new users are coming from whenever my app creates a new user record.

I'm grabbing - request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] which providers a url like:

```
http://twitter.com/
```

How can I take any URL and obtain just the domain?

Comment: The answer to parsing a known format in Ruby is rarely "use a regex", despite your tag. A better answer is nearly always "find the library someone else has written", or in this case the one already included in Ruby :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> require 'uri'
=> true 
> uri = URI.parse "http://twitter.com/"
=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000100994f98 URL:http://twitter.com/> 
> uri.host
=> "twitter.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a subdomain you can use the following: ActionDispatch::Http::URL.extract_domain("http://www.google.com")